# The data types varchar and varbinary(max) are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I am trying to insert into a FileTable using a stored procedure where my FileStream, FileName, FilePath will be parametrized. I have tried this but it throws an error

> The data types varchar and varbinary(max) are incompatible in the add operator

My stored procedure:

```
    @filePath VARCHAR(100),
    @fileName VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @file VARBINARY(MAX)
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT'+ @file +' = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '+ @filePath +', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x'

    EXEC(@Sql);

    INSERT INTO dbo.FileStore(name, file_stream)
        SELECT @fileName, @file
END
```

Comment: what are you passing into @file?

Comment: It was a mistake, I have updated the Question.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is here, but FWIW you don't need to convert @file to what you have declared it as `convert(VARBINARY(MAX),'+ @file +')`

Comment: I just Updated that too :D

Comment: And the error persist?

Comment: Yes it is still there

Comment: If you are trying to use Dynamic SQL to run something it doesn't look right to me. Put a PRINT @SQL before you execute it and see what is being returned and if that is what you want or not when I tried it nothing was returned, If you are just writing a SELECT statement it works but as dynamic SQL it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried it with PRINT @Sql and it is still giving the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is with @file variable inside your dynamic SQL.

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT'+ @file +' = CAST(bulkcolumn AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '+ @filePath +', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x'
```

When this is executed the @file variable will be replaced with the content of the variable. So if @file contains empty string (''), this will be resolved to:

```
SELECT  = CAST(bulkcolumn....
```

If @file is NULL the whole string will be NULLed..

If you need to use variables inside dynamic SQL, that is pass a value to the statement inside dynamic SQL or retrieve a value from it, you need to use sp_executeSQL and @params. Below is fully worked out and tested example. The @file variable inside the dynamic SQL statement is "mapped" to the @file variable in your stored procedure. sp_executeSQL knows to populate your @file variable with whatever is inside the @file variable in dynamic SQL. Note that even though these are named the same, they are different variables. If you are coming from .Net, dynamic SQL is like a method in .net, it has its own scope for variables. If it would make things clearer, you can use a different name for @file variable inside dynamic SQL.

```
declare @filePath VARCHAR(100) = 'insert full path'
     , @fileName VARCHAR(100) = 'insert file name';
DECLARE @file VARBINARY(MAX);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max);
declare @params nvarchar(max);


set @sql = N'SET @file = (SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N''' + @filePath + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x)';
set @params = N'@file varbinary(max) OUTPUT';

print @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @file = @file OUTPUT;
select @file;
```

Comment: Could you please Explain it ?

Comment: I've added more to explain. See also "substituting parameter values" in this article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx